# Find all solutions to $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|=1$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the solution set to $$|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|=1$$

I'm getting $z\in [-1,1]$, which is making me a little paranoid that it's purely a real number.  Can you check my work?

$$\begin{align}|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|=1 &\implies z+\sqrt{z^2-1} = e^{i\theta} \\ &\implies z^2-1 = (e^{i\theta}-z)^2=e^{i2\theta}-2ze^{i\theta}+z^2 \\ &\implies 2ze^{i\theta} = e^{i2\theta}+1 \\ &\implies z = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\right) = \cos(\theta) \\ &\implies z \in [-1,1]\end{align}$$

Comment: yes, but you should replace $\implies$ by $\Leftrightarrow$ for claiming you have solved it

Comment: This is correct. I saw the question before the work was added and posted pretty much the same thing, so this looks good.

Comment: This is a very impressive answer, there's no getting stuck in radicals or funny absolute values here. Good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have successfully proved that $z \in [-1, 1]$. You should also prove that every $z$ in that range is actually a solution. This isn't that hard, but you can't do it by just running your current proof backward; you squared both sides of your equation, which might have introduced extraneous solutions.